# Probability of an event happening after X our of Y attempts

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I have a work related question. Based on observation of a system, I determine that I have a 23% chance that when I run a test, the result will be above a certain threshold. Now, let's say that I repeat this same test 19 times, and each test is independent and has this same 23% chance of being above the threshold. I want to calculate the resulting probability of having 10 out of 19 events being above the threshold. It seems like the probability of having 10 out of 19 results above my threshold is much less than 23%, but I don't know how to quantify it.

Comment: Do you want the probability of having *exactly* $10$ of $19$ events above the threshold, or the probability of having *at least* $10$ of $19$ events above the threshold?

Comment: The former is about $0.364$ percent (that is, about $1$ time in $275$), and the latter is about $0.474$ percent (about $1$ time in $211$).

Comment: Symbolically, we have $\binom{19}{10}(0.23)^{10}(0.77)^{9}$ for the former, and $\sum_{k=10}^{19} \binom{19}{k}(0.23)^k(0.77)^{19-k}$ for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the wikipedia article on [the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), as it is exactly what you are describing and how Brian got the answer he commented before. I hope this clears the air. :)